# AVFoudationFramework: StillImageCapture: how to exit from AVFF?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I have a question or two about using AVFoundationFramework in XCode.

I downloaded AVCamDemo source code. I am trying to leverage the code in my app to replace UIImagePickerController (because it is slow) with the AVFF functionality.  However, I cannot figure out how to exit the AVFF code when "Done" button is tapped in the UI.  My app will provide the Done button.

Specifically, I need to know:

1. What do i need to **stop the capture session**? Just [session stopRunning] ??
2. My app's ViewController will invoke the AVFF, and will provide the "Done" button in the view controller that I will create for the AVFF functionality.  When the user taps the "Done" button, I need to stop the capture process and **exit back to my app**.  I am not sure how this can be done.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards, Sam.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Although you may also want to ensure you turn the video torch off if you had turned it on, and if you called `lockForConfiguration` on the device you should be sure to unlock it.
2. There is no "exiting". If you presented your view controller using `presentModalViewController:animated:`, use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`. If you pushed it onto a UINavigationController, pop it back off. If you did it some other way, dismiss it in the way appropriate for that method.

Comment: @Sam: You stop the capture session with `[session stopRunning]`. There is also some other cleanup that may be necessary: setting `torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOff` on the device if you had previously set it to `AVCaptureTorchModeOn` (otherwise the light will stay on even though your session is ended), and calling `unlockForConfiguration` on the device if you have an outstanding lock (from `lockForConfiguration`).

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question on AVFoundationFramework:

I don't exactly understand what you are not succeeding to do. Some general options:

1. [session stop] will stop capturing.
2. You can play with the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layer - that's what actually shows the camera preview.
3. All the ui code is in AVCamViewController - so you can just pop it from the stack, or remove it from superview - which ever is correct in your code.

If these don't help, please try to elaborate further on the problem, and perhaps supply some code.

Cheers,
Oded.